# Webpack 4: Target: NodeJS. Mode: production; MySQL Error: Received packet in the wrong sequence

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

Just upgraded to Webpack 4 and when building my server side code with `mode:'production'`.I get this MySQL `Error: Received packet in the wrong sequence.`

How can you prevent such mangling from happening?

Comment: I got the same question. Webpack is such a nightmare to deal with...

Comment: @pjb I will look into what solution I found de tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same problem when bundling with web pack. at last i have solved the issue.
i think it is an issue related to web-pack and babel-loader version mismatch.
i suggest following combinations in package.json
"babel-core": "^6.26.0",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
"mysql": "^2.15.0",
"serverless-webpack": "^2.2.3",
"webpack": "^3.5.5"